# I have a site where attachments in the wp_posts table have guid values of guid, how did this happen?

Tags: posts, images, attachments, guids

I realise comparing this particular website with all the other WP sites I've built that all the others have the image url in the guid column of the wp_posts table, yet this problem site just has "guid" as the value of the guid column for ALL it's image/attachment entries.

The site still seems to work fine... if I go to the "Media" area of the admin it lists all the uploaded images correctly. I assume the code is looking at the "_wp_attachment_metadata" fields in wp_postmeta to obtain their urls.

Ideally I want to

1. know how this happened - ie is this by design in some scenarios? was there a bug in WP at some point causing this?
2. Correct the issue replacing these values with the image urls as I have a function that tries to determine the image id of an image from it's url and that fails on this site ([based on this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671108/get-attachment-id-by-file-path-in-wordpress)).

Comment: Re: point 2. The guid is not intended to be an accurate representation of the URL to the attachment. It's merely using the URL as a unique identifier. To get the ID of an attachment based on the URL use `attachment_url_to_postid()`.

Comment: Amazing thanks @JacobPeattie write it up as an answer if you want some points!